# linq getting last of child collection

Tags: c#, linq

```
class User 
{
   public ICollection<Dispatch> Dispatches {set;get;}
   // other props
}

class Dispatch{
    public Status Status {set;get;}
}

enum Status{
  Done,
  Ok,
  Etc
}
```

I am interested in grouping Users by last dispatch status. 
I have tried couple things but failed. Any help?

Comment: At 15k reputation, do you really need to be told you should show what you have tried?..

Answer (score 3):

Provided by last dispatch you mean last in the Dispatches collection and that this collection is never null or empty, try this

```
users.GroupBy(user => user.Dispatches.Last().Status);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
var result = users.Select(user => user.Dispatches.Last().Status);
```